# NHibernate: returning List<EntityType> not List<Object[]> when using grouping

Tags: nhibernate

when using Nhiberante Criteria API or HQL with grouping, query returns list of arrays of entity properties `List<Object[]>` at which grouping was made. If I need to return only certain property how can I do that? preferably with Nhiberane API if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the **Transformers** class?

See section [16.1.5](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html)

Comment: This is freaking phenomenal.  Allows a quick way to remove the O(n) scenarios with some custom SQL and not needing another ORM mapper, I think.  Seems like the same thing can be done in Entity Framework, negating the need for Dapper, etc.

Answer (score 1):

With **HQL**, you just `SELECT` the properties you want:

```
var query = Session.CreateQuery("select p.Id, p.Price from Products p where p.Status = 'A'")
                   .List().Cast<object[]>();
```

It's similar with **NHibernate.Linq**:

```
var query = from p in Session.Linq<Product>()
            where p.Status == "A"
            select new
            {
                p.Id, p.Price
            };
```

Comment: I can't quite understand example with hql. What for Cast<object[]> is? When using grouping (unlike your example) data by default returned as List<object[]> (in your example it would hold Integer and Decimal). If I need only Prices of Products, how can I get them?